# fread segmentation fault reading database from binary file in c

Tags: c

I am writing a function, that helps me read a database of books from a binary file. However when using *fread* i am having a segmentation fault.

This is the function I am talking about.

```
Array *readdb (FILE *db, Array *ind) {
    Array *database = NULL;
    Book *book = NULL;
    indexbook *indentry;
    char *buffer, bytesdepillar = 0, titprintby[MAX_ENTRADA];
    int reader = 0;

    if (db == NULL || ind == NULL) 
        return NULL;

    database = malloc(sizeof(Array));

    initArray(database, INIT_ARR_SIZE);

    fseek(db, 0L, SEEK_END);
    bytesdepillar = ftell(db)/sizeof(char);
    fseek(db, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(bytesdepillar * sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bytesdepillar, db);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ind->used; i++) {
        book = malloc(sizeof(Book));
        indentry = (indexbook*) ind->array[i];

        reader = indentry->offset;

        book->bookID = indentry->key;
        reader+=sizeof(int);
        memcpy(book->ISBN, &buffer[reader], ISBN_LEN);
        reader+=ISBN_LEN;
        memcpy(titprintby, &buffer[reader], indentry->offset + indentry->size - reader);
        strcpy(book->title, strtok(titprintby, "|"));
        strcpy(book->printedBy, strtok(NULL, "|"));
    
        insertArray(database, book);
    }

    return database;
}
```

ind is the database index with the following structure:

```
typedef struct {
  int key;
  long int offset;
  size_t size; 
} indexbook;
```

The file is being opened with

```
    if ((dbf = fopen(db_name, "rb")) == NULL) {
        fclose(indf);
        printf("%s does not exist", db_name);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sizeof(char)` (or any other type based on `char`) is specified to *always* be `1`. You never need to multiply or divide by it.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to use a *debugger* to catch the crash? When and where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables at the time and location of the crash?

Comment: `chmod -r $db_name; ./a.out $dm_name` results in the wonderful error message "$db_name does not exist".  The file does exit, but the user does not have permission to read it.  No error message at all is better than an incorrect error message.  `man perror`

Comment: `indentry` is not initialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used gdb to check where segmentation fault happens. It happens in the following line:
`fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bytesdepillar, db);`

Comment: If you are 100% sure it crashed in `fread`, you should check whether the previous allocation succeeded. You should also check the value of `bytesdepillar`, is it a positive number? (`ftell` returns -1 on error).

Comment: `malloc` should be one more byte imo, because of the terminating character

Comment: @JuanR your are right, for some reason `bytesdepillar` is a negative number

Comment: [`ftell`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) will return `-1L` on failure and set `errno` to the error. Use e.g. `perror("ftell")` if `ftell` fails to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated in the comments section, when the line

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bytesdepillar, db);
```

is executed, the variable `bytesdepillar` has a negative value.

Since you declared the variable to be of type `char`, depending on your platform, it is probably only able to represent values between `-128` and `127`. If the call to `ftell` returns a value that is higher than `127`, it will probably (it is implementation-defined what exactly happens) be converted to a value between `-128` and `127`. That is most likely the reason why it is a negative value.

Therefore, I recommend that you change the declared type of `bytesdepillar` from `char` to `long`, which is the type returned by the function `ftell`.

If, after changing the declared type to `long`, the value continues to be negative, then it is probably due to the function `ftell` returning `-1` due to the function failing. In that case, you should verify that `db` refers to a valid stream (e.g. verify that the file has been successfully opened).

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that I declared it as a char, thanks a lot